# QtConcurrent number of arguments error

Tags: c++, qt, static-methods, qtconcurrent

I have a QMainWindow class.

```
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT
    ...
public:
    void insertVector();
    ...
};
```

and I have class SqlStorage to make operation with Data Base.

```
class SqlStorage : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
    ...
public:
    static void loadSQL();
    ...
};
```

In insertVector() method I try to asynchronously write in DB.

```
void MainWindow::insertVector()
{
    SqlStorage* _sqlStorage = new SqlStorage;
    QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(_sqlStorage, &SqlStorage::loadSQL);
}
```

But when I try to compile, I have error that: "term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments".

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 4):

When you want to call static member functions with `QtConcurrent::run`, you do it the same way you call a regular non-member function. Only difference is you include the class scope in it. Like this:

```
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(SqlStorage::loadSQL);
```

Comment: I try your code, but also have a error on complation (error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments)

Comment: Ok. I did it. Also, when I add arguments to this function, I have similar error.

Comment: @koch_kir I noticed your function is static, I updated my answer.